Is it possible to detect whether an enum has no fixed underlying type?
I have a template function that operates on a generic type T as input. I statically assert that T is an enum.
However, I want to constrain it further so that C-style enums (i.e. without fixed (explicit) underlying type) cannot be passed. Otherwise, the implementation risks invoking Undefined Behavior due to this (emphasis mine):

A value of integer or enumeration type can be converted to any complete enumeration type.
If the underlying type is not fixed, the behavior is undefined if the value of expression is out of range (the range is all values possible for the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all enumerators of the target enumeration).

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

All enumerations have an underlying type - user specified or not.

You may be interested in the C++23 featured std::is_scoped_enum

the underlying type may be implementation defined, but once you defined the enum the underlying type is fixed (by the implementation)

I meant "explicit", yes. Because UB happens only with non-explicit underlying type.

@NathanPierson Yes, that is part of the solution, but I still need to support unscoped enums with explicit underlying type

"Because UB happens only with non-explicit underlying type." why that? explicit or not the type can be wide enough or it can be not wide enough, you need to check, and you can check in both cases

see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type example at the bottom, there are 4 cases, two with explicit 2 without explitly specified underlying type. The way to query what the underlying type is is the same in for all, be it scoped or unscoped.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai


A value of integer or enumeration type can be converted to any complete enumeration type.
If the underlying type is not fixed, the behavior is undefined if the value of expression is out of range (the range is all values possible for the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all enumerators of the target enumeration).


https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast
So if an enum has values 0 and 1, casting the number "2" to the enum is UB on C-style enums. Not on C++ enums.

Actually the correct terminology is "fixed underlying type" so I'll edit back

Declares an enumeration without a fixed underlying type.
Declares an enumeration of fixed underlying type type.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum

Casting an int to an enum is always dangerous and a simple range check won't solve that. You could have enums with values 0, 9, and 100. Casting 42 to your enum will succeed, but won't be a valid value.

there are two ifs in that sentence. "if the type is not fixed" and "if the type is not wide enough". You focus on the first, but it is sufficient to have one of them false. And you can check the widht of the underlying type for any enum

No, it's not about "the type being wide enough". It's about the range of the bit-field defined by the enum , which cannot be checked. Check this:
https://godbolt.org/z/33fK3Yco6
There, it's clearly stated that the valid range of values is [0, 3]. Not [0, INT_MAX].

And what about this?

nice, why not add the paragraphs you quote and the example in the comments into the questions. We are asking for clarification out of curiosity not out of know-all-better. You have all the material to make this a very intersting question. Currently it is very easy to misunderstand it

@AndyG That's fine with respect to UB, because the valid range is 0-255. Sure, the enum does not have a valid value, but that's another story. The enum can still be used arithmetically (which is the main usage in the codebase I'm working on). Unfortunate, yes, but I can't really influence that.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai absolutely, will do!

I dont think there is something out of the box, but I would try to use expression sfinae to see if std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<A>>::max() can be static_casted to A, similar to what you did in the example that fails to compile, but my sinfae-foo is too lousy ;)

I don't believe there is any way to query the enum bit range size for a enum that has a fixed bit range.  (Just like there doesn't seem to be a way to programmatically at compile-time or run-time query the bit size of a bit-field member variable.)  Alas.

@AndyG if an enum (without fixed underlying type) has enumerators for 0, 9, and 100... then 42 is a valid value for that enum in C++. However 129 is not, even though the underlying type will likely be int or unsigned int. Similarly for your godbolt with enumerators for 0, 1, and 200. 5 is a valid value, but 257 is not.

@jeffgarrett I'm trying to make a distinction between what is valid in a domain versus what is valid in a type. You may actually want to perform arithmetic on enumerated types, but often a program has no idea what to do with an enumerated value that's not present in the list. If you're lucky, the developer has added a check for that case

Sure, a developer could assume that a subset of values will be found and fail to check that or handle the failure. Just like with other assumptions. Fortunately we have more tools in that case, and compilers warn. That's generally a quality issue. But that's not what this question is about. And the case in this question is much harder to catch.

This can SFINAE away if the underlying type can list-initialize  the enum:
template <typename T,
          typename L = std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<T>>,
          T min = T{L::min()}, T max = T{L::max()}>
consteval void check_enum() {}

This is sufficient to capture enums with a fixed underlying type.
Replacing the list-initialization with a static_cast in theory ought to allow enums without a fixed underlying type but sufficient range (a very unlikely case to be sure). However, for gcc this is bug #95701.
This can check it as a concept:
template <typename T>
concept full_range_enum = std::is_enum_v<T> && requires {
    { check_enum<T>() };
};

See:
enum A { a, b, c };
enum class B { a, b, c };
static_assert(!full_range_enum<A>);
static_assert(full_range_enum<B>);

godbolt
See also std::is_scoped_enum

Interesting idea! So if I understand correctly it may or may not invoke UB in the SFINAE clause. Is this legal, though? Because this was not allowed for example with std:: underlying_type, and they had to remove the UB to make it SFINAE-friendly: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0340r2.html

According to cppreference: "A substitution failure is any situation when the type or expression above would be ill-formed (with a required diagnostic), if written using the substituted arguments." Ill-formed is not the same as UB, so being pedantic about the language I don't think the above solution is legal?

I'm not sure the std::underlying_type is relevant? The UB was specified there and they changed the specification. Trying to sfinae on it wasn't ok because UB itself isn't a substitution failure. In this answer, we are substituting in a template default argument, which must be a converted constant expression and UB is one way to fail that.

I see, thanks. I still don't understand how the code works. First, GCC does not diagnose (yet) the UB of enum out-of-range in e.g. a constexpr variable. Second, if I ask the compiler to provide more info, it says: :6:27: error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'A' [-fpermissive]
6 |           T min = T{L::min()}, T max = T{L::max()}>
|                     ~~~~~~^~
Finally, I can replace L::min and L::max with hardcoded integer values 0 and 1 (valid range for the enum) and still the assert behaves in the same way. Why is that?

Actually it's only complaining because of brace-initialization. Using regular initialization with e.g. parenthesis instead of braces breaks the check. It's equivalent to writing "constexpr A x{0};" -> invalid conversion from "int" to "A". It does not really check the range of the enum.
I'm still OK with it, it does serve the purpose! I'm curious to understand why the compiler does not warn on scoped and/or enums with fixed underlying type.

Found the rationale:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum
An enumeration can be initialized from an integer without a cast, using list initialization, if all of the following are true:
...
The enumeration is either scoped or unscoped with underlying type fixed.
Great, so that's exactly what I want! Scoped enums or unscoped with fixed underlying type can be list-initialized, C-style enums cannot, since C++17.

You are correct. I mistook that for gcc diagnosing the UB (which I think it is supposed to, but does not).

Thank you for correcting me! I updated the answer to correct it and added a link to the GCC bug for range checking.

Looks great, thanks! I accepted the answer. It'd be great to add more info about why having UB in the template parameter is OK (since it's constant evaluated, it's actually ill-formed diagnostic required, not UB), feel free to add it!

@user1011113 cppreference uses vague language, but if you go to the draft standard, you will it spelled out that the underlying type of all scoped enums are fixed.

Inspired by the answer from Jeff Garret, I want to also post a slightly simpler solution, that also works on C++17 instead of requiring C++20 concepts. It also does not rely on UB being detected. It simply relies on the fact that only scoped enums or enums with fixed underlying type may be list-initialized.
It currently doesn't check that T is an enum but it would be trivial to add, the important part is distinguishing types of enums.
template <typename T, typename = void >
struct is_c_enum : std::true_type
{};

template <typename T>
struct is_c_enum<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{0})>> : std::false_type
{};

Godbolt
